# How to dynamically make tabs in a react-navigation Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Basically I'm developing an app that is supposed to be a SaaS. Different clients should be able to use the app according to their need. Suppose 10 stationary shops are my clients and they each have some different items to sell. For example:

[image]

Here the stationary seller only wants to sell Papers, pens and books. So I have made 3 tabs for that through the tab navigator (you can see the simple code in the back)

But this is hardcoded into the app. I want to make it into something generic which is reusable and dynamic, so that I can maybe get an array from my backend for stationer1 like

```
tabs = [Papers, Pens, Books]
```

and for stationer2 like

```
tabs = [Papers, Bags, Pens, Pencils, Paints]
```

and then the createMaterialTopTabNavigator makes use of this array to make the required tabs. I'm confused about how I can implement such a thing

Answer (score 0):

For all those facing a similar issue, I figured it out thanks to some help from this [link](https://medium.com/@abdelhalim.ahmed95/how-to-create-scrollable-and-dynamic-top-tabsbar-using-react-navigation-17ca52acbc51)

I'm using a fixed array in this code solution but obviously you can call your api server and get an array of items from it and then pass it on.

```
    let categories=['Papers', 'Bags', 'Pens', 'Pencils', 'Paints']
    categories = categories.reduce((val, tab) => {
        val[tab] = {
            screen: Appetizers
        }
        return val
        }, {})


    const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
        {
        ...categories   
        },

        {   
            swipeEnabled: true,
            tabBarOptions: {
                    style: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FECE17'
                    },
                    activeTintColor: 'black'  ,
                    inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
                    scrollEnabled: true





            }
        }
    );

    const tabNav = createAppContainer(Tabs);
    export default tabNav;
```

Works like a charm for me! Good luck